# Got an error handlerNotFound when invoking lambda function

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I've been learning aws lambda, so I decided to work with AWS SAM. I've configured everything, but I got this error for an unknown reason for me as fucntion createUser located in app.ts

Here is how my .yaml look

```
Resources:
  CreateUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: app.createUser
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        CreateUser:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /createUser
            Method: post
    Metadata: 
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: es2020
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - app.ts
```

I've  double checked the names of the function, I've checked where app.ts is stored, but I still got this error

!!!Edit 1

createUser function

```
export const createUser = async (event: any, context: any, callback: any) => {
    const { input } = event.arguments;
    console.log(input);
    try {
        return await UserService.createUser(input);
    } catch (error) {
        callback(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Include the code that defines/exports createUser and a file listing of your deployed Lambda ZIP file.

Comment: @jarmod added code of the function

Comment: @jarmod deployed zip file is the builded app.js, right?

Comment: I mean a listing of the deployed ZIP file e.g. `unzip -l somefolder/xyz.zip`. I am guessing that there is no file named `src/app.js`.

Comment: @jarmod There is file app.js, but not src directory

Comment: Right, that's what I was assuming. The file app.ts is in `src/` in your source code tree but app.js is not in `src/` in the deployed Lambda function. So your CodeUri is wrong. If app.js is in the root of your ZIP file then remove CodeUri. Otherwise, correct it.

Comment: @jarmod if I change CodeUri than I can't build the code. But with src/, Runtime.HandlerNotFound: app.createUser is undefined or not exporte

Comment: Per earlier question, where is app.js in the ZIP file that SAM built and deployed?

Comment: @jarmod app.js is located in CreateUserFunction/app.js

Comment: @jarmod I found out that the issue happence because of the return statment. It works fine without it

Comment: Strange. I don't see how a return statement inside the code of the Lambda function could possibly cause "handlerNotFound when invoking lambda function" but glad you've resolved the issue. PS ignore my earlier comments on CodeUri as they're mistakenly assuming how CodeUri is used.

Comment: change `callback(error);` to `console.error(error)`